# How to turn a function into a string without activation/use of any modules in javascript

Tags: javascript, tostring

Apparently this might look at a duplicate.. but let me explain the problem.
For the sake of the question ALL I can assume is that my code will be run, I do not know anything about the modules(if they're fake or something) and can only trust the things that get set in *instances that only my code will control(or originally set that they cannot be configured)*

What I want to do is to as my heading says, to convert a function to a string.. however all my attempts at conversion depend on a module that can be overwritten by the client

```js
Function.prototype.toString=()=>"pwned" //work of the client
//failed attempts to convert to string below
console.log(`${Object.keys}`) //"pwned"
console.log(Object.keys+'') //"pwned"
console.log(Object.keys.toLocaleString()) //"pwned"
```

Starting out with the only assumption I'm making(that my code is being run), I tried this below however it returns undefined(I thought returning nothing would somehow make it the default string)

```js
//infinityLoop is a function I write(all this is inside another self calling function) and the name suggests what it does
//the concept in this example is to run the code and if it smells anything suspicious, infinite loop
try{(function(href){
var symbol=Symbol.toPrimitive, c=1, here=arguments.callee
var testObj={[symbol]:function(){return here===arguments.callee.caller?c++:infinityLoop()}}
if(testObj-0!==1 || c!==2){throw "bruh"}
function str(item){
  var measure=null, unit={}, count=0
  function verifier(hint){
    const condition=hint!=="default" || this!==item || verifier.caller!==str || count!==0
    if(condition){infinityLoop()}  else{ measure=unit; count++ }
  }
  item[symbol]=verifier; const string=item+''
  if(measure!==unit || count !==1){throw "bruh"}
  delete item[symbol]; return string
}
str(Object.keys) //"undefined"
//I get to control the conversion but I still can't convert it ;-;
})()}catch{infinityLoop()}
```

Is it possible to convert a function to string without overwritable modules or is this a ridiculous impossible question?

Comment: This is not going to be helpful in the slightest but I have to mention that serializing a function is an extremely difficult task, especially in a language like JS. Your example tries to serialize a constant function which is the absolute simplest case. Functions can reference values outside of their scope and turns out this is an unsolved problem. There is existing work like [Spores](https://scalacenter.github.io/spores/spores.html) or the terrible unsafe solution frameworks like Spark do but you will run into a lot issues if you start dealing with more complicated functions

Comment: yea I know I gave a simple example but I just want to know if it is possible to turn it into a string without the modules

Comment: What is your purpose? Why do you need syntax as string? If you're looking for static analysis, you can check esprima for tokenization and parse trees.

Comment: well I'm trying to determine if a function is user overwritten or not and I was using string conversion to check, then I realised that string conversion clutches heavily on modules that the client can overwrite anyway.. so *I'm trying to see it as a string to find out if a function is legitimate* as silly as that sounds @html_programmer

Comment: Given you can overwrite any module or other piece of code by a client in javascript, this is probably not possible by your standards.

Comment: Can you say more about what problem you're trying to solve?  It sounds like you're looking for a solution to something (like, get a result from a client, but have proof of work it was done in a legitimate way) which has known techniques, but asking directly to implement your own envisioned solution

Comment: The point I'm not getting is why you need to check if a function has been overridden... you are the designer of the app; users can't override functions. You are the one who determines if it should be overridden or not. If an external module overrides a common prototype and causes bugs, I would strongly consider ditching it. Maybe I'm missing something you're trying to do, or I don't get the story right.

Comment: @html_programmer  users can absolutely tamper with code in a browser and given other language and execution environments, javascript in a browser is one of the easier scenarios to that in

Comment: Yes of course they 'could', but why should you care if they break your app by doing custom stuff in the console... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: you can override most.. things like window or document, nah.. or things like in the second example

Comment: and as for what I'm trying to do @possum let's say I have a way of loading this script that WILL either run or the real code meant for the client won't load and when the real code loads I want to make sure that the modules aren't spoofed.. before realising that string conversion was module dependent, I had code that would be able to fully lock up the modules in the window in about 100-200ms

Comment: If the user can manipulate the "real" code they can manipulate whatever code you use to check or block.  Users can overwrite not only modules but any function or part of a function including system calls.  The whole idea of what you're trying to do is limit and control what code is running on a user's own processor, which is a huge topic and one not in the developer's favor with modern hardware (to say nothing about the ethical problems of dictating what someone else can do with their property).  The best you can probably do is heavily obfuscate and employ encryption techniques.

Comment: To add to this, the common and secure solution to ensuring code is executed as you like is to employ a backend where it runs in an environment you control.

Comment: @possum let's say I have a loader before that basically runs things without variables and even for the indexes uses randomly calculated indexes, junk processing and on specific conditions adds specific text to an array(against deobfuscation and especially against regex).. then just send back the array.. all that forerunner has to do is make sure that the communication from server to client is only listened to by it(the other way around doesn't matter)

Comment: This is getting off topic for a question.  You'll get a better discussion taking this to a different venue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241328/discussion-between-the-bomb-squad-and-possum).

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are trying to implement security for something. Can you explain what you are trying to secure and what the threat model is?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

If you don't control and/or trust the environment that is running the code, you also cannot control and/or trust what the code does.

Comment: yea I wanted to know if it was possible.. if there's no way to know if the function is from the environment(as in not spoofed by a client) there's no point in the tool I was trying to make I guess.. thanks for the advise though :D